# Как многократно можно обращаться к выполнению AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-asynctask

Суть вопроса в том, что есть AsyncTask в котором я получаю JSON с сайта, и передаю выборку в MainActivity.
Первое обращение к AsyncTask создается при запуске программы. Также в форме есть кнопка обновить данные, при нажатии которой я хочу повторно обновить данные с сайта обратившись к AsyncTask, но получаю сообщение что он уже выполняется и может быть выполнен только один раз.

Прошу помощи в решении задачи. Также если есть предложение по изменению AsyncTask на другое решение тоже буду рад. :)

### - Публикую код -

**MainActivity.java**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse{

```
Button click;
public static TextView data;
GetDataFromSite asyncTask = new GetDataFromSite();
String str = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fachetdata);

    ReadJSONDataFromFile();

    asyncTask.delegate = this;
    asyncTask.execute();

    click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           asyncTask.execute();
       }
    });
}

@Override
public void processFinish(String JSON_Write_Data){
    WriteJSONDataToFile(JSON_Write_Data);
    ReadJSONDataFromFile();
}

void WriteJSONDataToFile(String JSONDW) {
     try {
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("nano_data.json", MODE_PRIVATE)));
        bw.write(JSONDW);
        bw.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

void ReadJSONDataFromFile() {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("nano_data.json")));
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            data.setText(str);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

---

**GetDataFromSite.java**

```
public class GetDataFromSite extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> {
...
Тут переменные
...
  public AsyncResponse delegate = null;
  @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        try {
...
Тут качаем JSON данные с сайта и пишем их в переменную Full_Info которая передается в MainActivity и пишеться в фаил в WriteJSONDataToFile
...
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        MainActivity.data.setText(this.Full_Info);
        delegate.processFinish(this.Full_Info);
    }
}
```

---

Ну и интерфейс
**AsyncResponse.java**

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
    void processFinish(String JSON_Write_Data);
}
```

Comment: Так создавайте новый и запускайте. И первый создавайте перед выполнением, зачем он нужен раньше?

Comment: Кстати какое поведение ожидается если пользователь нажал рефреш, когда еще не закончилось первое обновление? а какое поведение когда пользователь открываете активити второй раз (допустим есть кэш и сохраненные данные)? Как поведение меняется если первый раз была ошибка или данные не скачались? Меняется ли поведение от таймаутов? Короче есть много тонкостей.

Comment: Другое решение Retrofit заюзать для получения. По дуфолту асинхронно. Просто и удобно

Comment: Всем спасибо за то, что отозвались :).  ув. Eugene Krivenja - Я незнаю сколько раз пользователь будет обновлять данные, есть конечно вариант создавать новый AsyncTask_i где i++, но я еще незнаю как это отразиться на использовании памяти. хотелось бы останавливать поток по окончании процедуры обновления данных.

Comment: Всем спасибо за то, что отозвались :).  ув. @Eugene Krivenja - Я незнаю сколько раз пользователь будет обновлять данные, есть конечно вариант создавать новый AsyncTask_i где i++, но я еще незнаю как это отразиться на использовании памяти. хотелось бы останавливать поток по окончании процедуры обновления данных.

Comment: ув. @Serge Markov - Все эти вопросы у меня еще висят в голове и я только в начале пути :). Ответы.- 1. Кнопка повторно если незакончен запрос - думал модально повесить прогресс бар, но можно сделать проверку если незакончено не принимать запрос. 2. Активити второй раз первым делается запрос к файлу сохраненных данных с пометкой времени и даты последнего обновления, после чего выполняется попытка обновление данных. 3. Отобразить пользователю сообщение попытка №2, №3, "нет связи с сервером", и отобразить последние удачно скачанные данные. 4. смотри пункт 3. Я понимаю, что есть много тонкостей.

Comment: ув. @Романыч спасибо за совет если уменя неполучиться с тем что я сейчас навоял то скорее всего перейду на Retrofit.

Comment: Retrofit это современное решение. К тому же он проще реализуется и лишен многих проблем Asynk

Comment: @Victor выложите вашу асинктаску и где вы её вызываете. Так вам ответят быстрей

Comment: Retrofit не решит вопросы, которые озвучил @SergeMarkov, поэтому можете не торопиться переходить. "хотелось бы останавливать поток по окончании процедуры обновления данных" -- о каком потоке речь? О своих потоках AsyncTask сам заботится, отработал и забыл.

Comment: @Serge Markov - я выложил код. :)

Comment: @Shwarz Andrei - я выложил код :)

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja - я выложил код :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если исправлять в лоб, без рефакторинга, который тут не помешал бы, то вот так:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
  data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fachetdata);

  ReadJSONDataFromFile();

  startAsyncTask();

  click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       startAsyncTask();
   }
  });
}

private void startAsyncTask() {
  GetDataFromSite asyncTask = new GetDataFromSite();
  asyncTask.delegate = this;
  asyncTask.execute();
}
```

Должно работать при условии, что `delegate` будет вызываться в UI треде.

Comment: ув. @Eugene Krivenja, Примного благодарствую. Я тут прочитал такое слово "рефакторинг". Любопытное. :). Почитал и понял, что у меня "грязный код". Можете какиенибудь наставления дать? :). И про UI тред можно в двух словах?

Comment: `public static TextView data;` - вот от этого избавиться однозначно :)

Comment: У вас идет запись в файл, как вы должны понимать, писать в один файл из нескольких тредов просто так нельзя. Но так как вызов делегата идет из `onPostExecute`, который отрабатывается в UI треде (который всегда один), запись в файл будет происходить последовательно, сколько бы AsyncTask-ов вы не запускали.

Comment: ув. @Eugene Krivenja, от TextView data избавлюсь, он мне нужен был только для промежуточного отображения :). Я сейчас просто извлекаю JSON на экран без парсинга, но в последствии будет парсинг и присвоение полям на форме в xml. Скажите я сейчас сталкнулся со следующей бедой, хочу повесить ProgressDialog, Нашел кучу примеров но натыкаюсь на одну проблему, я обьявляю `ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this)` в GetDataFromSite.java но он мне ругается :). Пробовал обернуть в процедуру но тщетно.

Comment: Задавайте новые вопросы, это не форум. Отвечу кратко: изменением UI должна заниматься Activity, из которой асинхронная операция вызывается. Тогда и вопросов такого рода не возникнет.

Comment: Все понял, спасибо!